# jquery.ui datepicker range not allow choosing same day

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker for choosing hotel dates.I need the datepicker to not allow the user select the same day in both calendars
here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/h3wGx/)

This is how it should work:
- you can't add a "to" date lower than "from" date
- you can't choose the same day for both "to" and "from" dates

this is the code I have:

```
$( "#booking-from" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate: 0,
    firstDay: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        //$( "#booking-to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );           
        /*var day1 = $("#booking-from").datepicker('getDate').getDate() + 1;                 
        var month1 = $("#booking-from").datepicker('getDate').getMonth();             
        var year1 = $("#booking-from").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
        year1 = year1.toString().substr(2,2);
        var fullDate = day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1;*/         

        $( "#booking-to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
$( "#booking-to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate: '+2d',
    changeMonth: true,
    firstDay: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        //$( "#booking-from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", $('#booking-to').datepicker('getDate') );
    },
    onSelect: function (){
        calculateBooking();
    }
});

$("#booking-from").datepicker('setDate', '+1');
$("#booking-to").datepicker('setDate', '+8');
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this three lines in your `onClose` event of the `from` datepicker. This doesn't require any changes to your dateformat.

```
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {         
    var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
    $( "#booking-to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newMin );
}
```

<kbd>[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/3/)</kbd>

**EDIT**

If you want the same behaviour the other way round include this in the `onClose` event of the `to`picker.

```
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var newMax  = new Date(maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1));
    $( "#booking-from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",  newMax);
}
```

<kbd>[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/4/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you change the date format to ISO (`yy-mm-dd`) you can take advantage of the JavaScript `Date` object and easily add another date:

```
var actualDate = new Date(selectedDate);
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);  
$( "#booking-to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newDate );
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h3wGx/1/

In case you want to keep your original date formatting you could use jQuery Datepicker's altFormat option: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat